# "DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputQuery" is deleting the query

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm encountering a problem where `DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputQuery` deletes the query itself the second time it is run.

Is there any workaround/patch for this bug (at least seems like a bug to me)?

Comment: Could you post the actual code you are using (even if you have to anonymise it)? Have you tried putting a break point before the call to DoCmd and stepping through and seeing if the query really is being deleted during the second run?

Comment: It is rather weird actually. I have made a copy of the database, and the copy is working correctly now.

Comment: I have also seen this behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re: your comment.

Did you do a file copy, or did you copy the objects between two databases? IF the second, you might want to try doing a compact and repair on a file-copy of the original.

You might even want to try that on the real original.

Comment: I did not copy anything between databases.

Answer (score 1):

I think the behaviour you described "...deletes the query itself, the second time it is run" occurs when the query returns no records.

Comment: I tested this after you shown me this possibility, but it does not seem to be the case. In fact this time, I ran it twice and it worked. Very weird.

Answer (score 1):

even 2007 has this problem, it is happening to me also, but very randomly. Sometimes I can run it many times before the bug happens, other times it happens right away, it's a small database, 29 records, and a tiny query, so it's definitely a bug in access

Answer (score 1):

I know it's been awhile since the original post, but I have found a solution that I did not see here. I'm using Access 2010. It seems that almost everytime I execute `DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputQuery...`, my saved query still appears in my list of queries, but the SQL gets wiped out, which subsequently deletes my output file too from the network.

I just reset the SQL before calling `DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputQuery...`

```
CurrentDb.QueryDefs("MyQuery").SQL = "SELECT..."
```

and then call

```
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputQuery, "MyQuery"...
```

So far so good.

Answer (score 0):

it happens to me too.
I'm using Access 2003.

The only workaround I've found is to preserve a copy of the original mdb, this way I can restore the mdb when it happens.

It seems that Access 2007 doesn't have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround is to change the original query to a make table query, and then use

```
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputTable, TableName, ...
```

It means you have an extra table hanging around, but you could always do a delete table in code or via a query afterwards to clean up.