# Access 2003/2007 Query contents wiped

Tags: ms-access, corruption

Has anyone else come across a situation where the contents (SQL statement) of an Access 2003 or 2007 was completely wiped (the Query object still exists, the inner SQL does not)?

Does anyone know what causes this?

I've just had this happen to me again. 2 queries run from a Macro's OutputTo actions to generate 2 Excel files. I ran the Macro a few times then suddenly no more SQL statement in both Queries.

Answer (score 0):

No, I've never seen this happen.  And I've read pretty much all the postings in the Usenet and Microsoft newsgroups mentioning corruption for the last ten years or more.

But I'm wondering.  Do multiple users share this MDB?   We've had a few bizarre postings with respect to Access 2007 losing VBA code.

Comment: In both cases it was a single user database running on a local hard-drive (network not an issue).
I haven't had any issues losing VBA code though.

Answer (score 0):

I have accidently done this in VBA code in MS Access by creating QueryDef object whose name that matched an existing query.

Answer (score 0):

Yup I've had this happen in a 2003 database - I thought perhaps the database had been corrupted so I rebuilt it from scratch this time using Access 2010, but it has just happened to me again. Macro / button has been working as expected for months, but after I changed 1 line of VBA code in a completely unrelated part of the application (setting a field to null instead of ""), this query wiping has started again.

I run a macro triggered from a button which outputs the results of a SELECT to a file. I've worked out the specific steps I can take to trigger the Query being wiped out, however if I check the query still exists in between each step then the query doesn't get wiped! Obviously this is not a solution for the application users.

I have found in another stackoverflow question [Weird Bug: "DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputQuery" is deleting the query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/545310/weird-bug-docmd-outputto-acoutputquery-is-deleting-the-query) a work around I am going to try - change the built-in macro ExportWithFormatting to run code instead and restate the SQL before running the output command.

Comment: After a few hours of testing, so this work-around has been successful for me.